# Styling JavaFX Popover

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I need to style a Popover from ControlsFX, but am failing to do so.

I have my own xxx.css stylesheet that I add to a scene, and I've (obviously) successfully styling many JavaFX Controls...

I have set this in the stylesheet (copied and modified from popover.css in ControlsFX):

```
.popover > .border {
    -fx-stroke: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    -fx-stroke-width: 0.5;
    -fx-fill: rgba(30 , 30, 30, .95);
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0,0,0,.2), 10.0, 0.5, 2.0, 2.0);
}
```

But the Popover never gets the border style. How do I get the Popover to pick the style up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `PopOver` is displayed in a different window, you can't set your style on the primary scene, but on the `PopOver`control.

If you look at how the style is applied to the control in its skin class `PopOverSkin`:

```
stackPane = new StackPane();
stackPane.getStylesheets().add(
            PopOver.class.getResource("popover.css").toExternalForm());
stackPane.getStyleClass().add("popover");
```

where this `stackPane` can be accessed with:

```
@Override
public Node getNode() {
    return stackPane;
}
```

you just need to add your style sheets to that stack pane, right after you have access to the skin, that is, when the popOver is shown:

```
popOver.show(...);

((Parent)popOver.getSkin().getNode()).getStylesheets()
    .add(getClass().getResource("MyPopOver.css").toExternalForm());
```